# How can I inject a js when a div become visible?

Tags: vue.js

I'd need to keep initial page load as fast as possible so I'm trying to avoid loading gmaps, paypal, stripe or similar js when the page loads as I need them only after the user clicked a button and a div gets visible.

I have a

```
<div class="container" v-if="step != '0'" v-cloak>
...
</div>
```

I tried to put "`<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>`" within the div but this doesn't work, the js is loaded during the initial page load.

How can I inject js in Conditional Rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Watch the step and append script to DOM:

```js
   data() {
       return {
           //...
           jsInjected: false,
           //...
       }
   },
   watch: {
       step(val, oldVal) {
           if(! this.isInjected && val != '0') {
                let s = document.createElement("script");
                s.type = "text/javascript";
                s.src = "https://js.stripe.com/v3/";
                document.head.appendChild(script);

                this.jsInjected = true; // prevent to append more than once.
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Ok, so I have to inject it via js, I was looking for something that let me keep the script tag in the html but this could work, thanks.